# Can't get Android slide menu working

Tags: android

I found this awsome slide menu but I can't get it working, can someone that maybe already used it give me some help/hints on how to get it working?
I just need the left menu.

Here's the github project: https://github.com/TangKe/SlideMenu

Comment: do you wanna use navigation drawer?

Comment: yes i'd like to use it

Comment: follow this tutorial it works http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/